# How can I change my gnome shell theme (user themes extension) using the terminal?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, 21.10

I want to change my gnome shell theme from the user-theme extension using the terminal. I did `dconf watch /` to check what changing the theme does and the path it gave me was

> ```
> /org/gnome/shell/extensions/user-theme/name
>
> "Theme-name"
> ```

So I try to do `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme name "Theme name"` but it didn't work (Output: `No such schema “org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme"`)

Comment: how did you install user-theme extension? What is the output of `gnome-extensions list`

Comment: @UnKNOWn my output from gnome-extensions list  `user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
gnome-ui-tune@itstime.tech
logomenu@aryan_k
blur-my-shell@aunetx
no-overview@fthx
ding@rastersoft.com
ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com` I installed the extension from https://extensions.gnome.org/

Comment: Ok what is the output of `gnome-extensions show user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com`

Comment: @UnKNOWn `Name: User Themes
  Description: Load shell themes from user directory.
  Path: /home/parker/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
  URL: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell-extensions
  Version: 46
  State: ENABLED`

Comment: Ok. by the way we install this extension, it seems the schemas are not compiled. we have two options, either to compile the schemas or to use the below command. But did you try the dconf way to set the theme?

Comment: `gsettings --schemadir .local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/schemas set org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme name "theme_name"`

Comment: @UnKNOWn How would you do that using dconf? Something like: `dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/user-theme/name "theme-name" ` ? Edit: I just saw your new comment. Thanks it works.

Comment: yes something like that only, I dont have good command on dconf. but, since using dconf you got the result, it is possible too to set what you want via dconf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct command to change your Shell theme using the terminal is:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/user-theme/name "'theme_name'"
```

where `theme_name` is obviously the name of the theme you want to use.

Note the use of both `"` and `'` for quoting the theme's name. This is because a key's values should be in [GVariant format](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/gvariant-format-strings.html), as you can read in [`man dconf`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/dconf.1.html):

```
VALUE arguments must be in GVariant format, so e.g. a string must include explicit quotes:
"'foo'". This format is also used when printing out values.
```

Comment: Now it makes sense, thanks for the update!

Comment: You're welcome!